# How to get NODE_ENV to a Rails 7 with Propshaft to a javascript library?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tippyjs, import-maps, propshaft

Trying to use `tippy.js` library on a brand new `Rails 7` application with `Propshaft` without `webpack` or `sprockets`, loading it via `Importmap` and getting an error on the browser's inspector saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`.

At the [library's FAQ](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v5/faq/#i-m-getting-uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined) there is a related question but that will require using `Gulp` or `Rollup` which is not used at this project.

How can `NODE_ENV` get through javascript stack at `process.env.NODE_ENV` so the library can see it?

Comment: I've had the same issue and can't figure it out in my rails 7 project either. I don't have node running, and don't need to, nor do I want a bunch of other unused libraries just to get the process.env vars set.